# Casting IIdentity to IMyIdentity with extra properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have to extend IIdentity (System.Security.Principal.IIdentity) to IMyIdentity with couple of more properties as follows

```
public interface IMyIdentity : IIdentity
{
    public bool IsXyz {get;}
    public bool IsAbc {get;}
}
```

Now when I used to perform

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as IIdentity
```

it used to work fine, but now when I perform

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as IMyIdentity
```

it doesn't work and casts to null, which is a problem for me

Whole method chunk is shown below

```
        public virtual IMyIdentity GetCurrentUserIdentity(bool ignoreXyz)
        {
            if (_userProfile != null && _userProfile.IsAnonymous && (ignoreXyz || _userProfile.PointId > 0))
            {
                return new UserIdentity
                           {
                               Name = _userProfile.UserName,
                               IsAuthenticated = true,
                               AuthenticationType = UserIdentity.AUTHENTICATION_ANONYMOUS
                           };
            }
            else
            {
                return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as IMyIdentity;
            }
        }
```

Could you please let me know what should I do to solve this?

Comment: how do you *assign* to the `HttpContext.Current.User` ?

Comment: @BrokenGlass I didn't get you exactly, but yeah you can cast from HttpContext.Current.User.Identity to IIdentity because User.Identity is of type IPrincipal.IIdentity, which is fine

Comment: that's why the original cast works of course, but using a custom interface can never work unless you have assigned a class instance that actually implements that interface to `HttpContext.Current.User`

Comment: @BrokenGlass yup, I got a concrete class UserIdentity, which implements IMyIdentity. I tried (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as UserIdentity) as IMyIdentity, which doesn't work too? Can you point me in right direction? I can manually transfer object properties, but would love to implement some sort of casting from outside

Comment: Where do you **assign** you UserIdentity to `HttpContext.Current.User` ? You still haven't answered this question

Comment: @BrokenGlass Sorry for that mate, I added/edited the method chunk above where it falters. Basically inside the ApplicationController (a global state controller), I use the output of this method to set the UserIdentity based on our requirement

Comment: Again. What is the relation between HttpContext.Current.User.Identity and UserIdentity??

Comment: @BrokenGlass I am probably going to the manual property conversion as shown in below answer to fix this issue. I thought that it would automatically cast it to IMyIdentity but I realized the issue that it's not possible as pointed out by BrokenGlass. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I at last thought of going with the property conversion from HttpContext.Current.User.Identity to my type as follows

```
public virtual IMyIdentity GetCurrentUserIdentity(bool ignoreXyz)
{
    if (_userProfile != null && _userProfile.IsAnonymous && (ignoreXyz || _userProfile.PointId > 0))
    {
        return new UserIdentity
                   {
                       Name = _userProfile.UserName,
                       IsAuthenticated = true,
                       AuthenticationType = UserIdentity.AUTHENTICATION_ANONYMOUS
                   };
    }
    else
    {
        return new UserIdentity
                   {
                       Name = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.UserName,
                       IsAuthenticated = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated,
                       AuthenticationType = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.AuthenticationType
                   };                           
    }
}
```